# SignalR on Home Network

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, networking, signalr

**Edit/Summary**

After a lot of trial and error, Paul Kearney - pk helped lead me to the answer, although I still don't know *why* this happens, at least I know how to get it to work.

Quick Summary: Clients can connect to port 8080 on my laptop when I'm directly connected to my network at work. Clients cannot connect to port 8080 when I'm on a home network. To solve this, I created a firewall rule (on my laptop) to allow inbound traffic on 8080. I'd really like to know why this is the case. Does my laptop's Windows Firewall service actually change its settings based on the network I'm connected to?

---

Note: **This all works when I'm on my network at work, but it doesn't work on my home network, or someone else's home network. The host computer (my laptop) is the same at both locations.**

I have a web app that uses SignalR. **Everything works when I run the web app on the same machine as where the SignalR host is running. When I try to connect from a different machine, I get this error**:

```
> GET http://10.0.0.13:8080/signalr/hubs net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Cannot read property 'client' of undefined.
```

That error comes from my index.html page:

```
<script src="http://10.0.0.13:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

From the research that I've done, I know that I shouldn't be using `localhost` in my SignalR URL. So I used an asterisk. This is in my self-hosted SignalR app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://*:8080";
        using (WebApp.Start(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
public class RaceHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

And this is my JavaScript to connect:

```
  var signalRUrl = 'http://10.0.0.13:8080/signalr';

  $.connection.hub.url = signalRUrl;
  var hub = $.connection.raceHub;  // proxy reference to hub

  // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
  hub.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
      receiveSignalRMessage(name, message);
  };

  $.connection.hub.start();  // Start the connection.
```

Like I said, this all works locally. But it doesn't work from another machine. I do not have Windows Firewall enabled, so that's not the issue. Any ideas?

HTTPS didn't work. It works when I'm on my network at work, but not at home. The configuration is the same. Must have something to do with my home network.

Also, this is what the page looks like when it's working properly:

[image]

And this is what happens when it's not working:

[image]

Comment: not caused from SignalR API, i dont know without seeing the machine infos but it can be result from IP versions. can you prove the IP Versions?

Comment: What do you mean by IP versions? IPv4 and IPv6? And what does it mean to prove them? Just that they are all IPv4 or IPv6?

Comment: I actually want to say error is not caused from SignalR, most likely from Network. May be try to plus sign instead of asterisk.

Comment: FYI: plus sign didn't work.

Comment: Is there another application that's running that uses port 8080?

Comment: No. `netstat -na | find "8080"` only shows something when my SignalR host is running. I should point out that I'm doing this on my home network. There is no domain. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: if there is proxy setting enabled that you use browser, this error would occur.

Comment: have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Chrome and IE.

Comment: did you try both wireless and wired connection?

Comment: To the person that downvoted this question, leaving some explanation would be helpful so that SO functions like it was intended, a knowledgebase...if you don't leave feedback, how can the OP improve the question to the betterment of SO users? Idiot.

Comment: Did you try watching network traffic using a packet sniffer (such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) and then comparing?

Comment: Are you updating the value of `signalRUrl` in javascript when you move from your work to home? I highly doubt the IP address of your laptop is the same in both locations.

Comment: If you are using a desktop version of Windows, you can set the location of each network to either public, work or home. The location you choose has security implications and affects which ports are open in the Windows Firewall.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Yes, I'm updating the IP address.

Comment: @PaulKearney-pk I still have this same issue even with the Windows Firewall service turned off.

Comment: @PaulKearney-pk I finally got it working based on your lead. I added a firewall rule to allow port 8080. I'm not sure why it was necessary since it worked on the network at my office. But now it's also working on a home network. If you'd like to answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulKearney-pk An IT friend of mine emailed me some information that would make a perfect answer for this question. I posted it as an answer below, but you deserve the credit. If you'd like to copy/paste my answer into a new answer, I'll accept it and delete mine.

Comment: Thanks @BobHorn - I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Full disclosure - @BobHorn typed up this answer based on my comments)*

There are different firewall settings on your machine, depending on the type of network you are attached to.

Have you ever noticed when you connect to a new network for the very first time, it asks you to define it as "work, private, public, home, etc"?

Whatever you choose for that network is sticky, and the related firewall policy is applied when you are on that type of network.

To check this, you can either completely turn off your firewall, or make sure inbound port 8080 is open for all firewall profiles, especially "home" networks and/or the "home" firewall profile.

ahh.. so you say your windows firewall is off. Are you sure it's not OFF only for the WORK network profile, but enabled for the HOME network profile ?

To troubleshoot this, I would put wireshark on one of the client computers trying to connect to port 8080 at home, and see how/why it's being blocked or cannot connect.

You can also try to telnet to port 8080 from the client machine at home (if the Telnet Client feature is enabled). You'll know right away if the port is open and connection succeeds, or a big fat denied. Quick and easy test. type TELNET ServerIPAddress PortNumber from a command line. If Telnet command not found, you need to turn on the Telnet Client in Windows Features/Components.

Answer (score 0):

Does your network use IP security? You might try using HTTPS instead to see if that alleviates anything.

Comment: HTTPS didn't work. It works when I'm on my network at work, but not at home. The configuration is the same. Must have something to do with my home network.

Comment: The component that the server uses to receive requests is based on HTTPListener- you can check the URL you're using with the documentation for that class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.httplistener

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your work network is blocking your IP. Try whitelisting your home IP on your work network.

Comment: If that was true, then the client computers wouldn't be able to pull up the web page in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure the siganlR connection is the same server as the web page? It is possible that they are different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that your laptop's IP address changes from one network (i.e. work) to another (i.e. home), but you may not be updating the value of the `signalRUrl` variable in your javascript file accordingly, thus the client side of your app is looking for a hub at an IP address that doesn't exist on your home network.

When you change networks, you need to update the value of signalRUrl in javascript to reflect the current IP address of the host machine.

Comment: I am updating the IP address when I switch networks, so this isn't the issue.